# How do I fill empty values with 0?

Tags: kql

I've got the following code

```
MyDatabase
| project SessionId, NumberOfAlarms
```

I've got some values on "NumberOfAlarms" which are a blank cell, and I want to put fill those cells with 0 instead. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: MyTable seems more suitable than MyDatabase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[coalesce()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/coalescefunction)

```
let MyTable = datatable(SessionId:int, NumberOfAlarms:int)
[
    1,14 ,2,62, 3,int(null) ,4,11 ,5,int(null) ,6,37 ,7,12
];
MyTable
| project SessionId, NumberOfAlarms = coalesce(NumberOfAlarms, 0)
```

| SessionId | NumberOfAlarms |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 14 |
| 2 | 62 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 11 |
| 5 | 0 |
| 6 | 37 |
| 7 | 12 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA12OsQrCMBiE9zzFjS3cYNLaguLg6KAOuolD2v5CJW2lSQfBhzeCiHq3HHfDd04CtvejrZxghcaG6JiTg3jfDv2mWbR9IHZTV8m4v6ydHTv/6lJ1UojS1DloWBgiYxySfnIuBXNqDc6/q4JZCZbURp2X6o1VD9zG4Sp1wAf6D4zX6sE68bUkvwsxS59oZSRxxAAAAA==)